# Disable plugin contributions in Eclipse RCP Application

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp

I frequently had this problem and didn't find a solution yet: Whenever I write a new Eclipse RCP based application and include plugins from the Eclipse platform, I 'inherit' UI contributions from some of those plugins.

Most of this contributions (menu entries, keyboard shortcuts, property pages) are useful but sometimes I'd rather disabled some of these contributions, just because I really do not need them and they might confuse the users.

Does anyone know of the official or a practical way to disable/prohibit selected contributions in Eclipse RCP applications?

Comment: I don't think removeContributionFactory() is for disabling *all* contribution, but is rather a "`dispose`" mechanism used for un-registering one view/menu contribution, and I was proposing to use that for explicitly remove contributions coming from *other* plugins.

Comment: So it is: a/ not *exactly* what you are looking for, b/ not easy, since you have to detect those contributions and remove them. But this is what I have got so far.

Comment: re-reading your comment: no you are not disabling *all* contribution (from *all* other plugins), but you might ending up disabling all contributions from one given external plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the Eclipse "Activities" API.  It allows you to hide contributions based on ID.

A few links:

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_add_activities_to_my_plug-in%3F
- http://blog.vogella.com/2009/07/13/eclipse-activities/
- http://random-eclipse-tips.blogspot.com/2009/02/eclipse-rcp-removing-unwanted_02.html
- http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/workbench_scalability.htm

Answer (score 3):

The only method which comes close to do that would be:

[`IMenuService::removeContributionFactory()`](http://kickjava.com/src/org/eclipse/ui/menus/IMenuService.java.htm)

Paul Webster has been calling for a [`IMenuService::addOverride()`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Menu_Contributions/RCP_removes_the_Project_menu) to change the visibility of the menu, preventing any contribution, but that idea has not been integrated yet.

You can see an example of removing a contribution in this [`org.eclipse.ui.tests.menus.MenuBuilder`](http://mail.eclipse.org/viewcvs/index.cgi/org.eclipse.ui.tests/Eclipse%20UI%20Tests/org/eclipse/ui/tests/menus/MenuBuilder.java?view=co) class;

```
public static void removeMenuContribution() {
    if (!PlatformUI.isWorkbenchRunning()) {
        return;
    }
    IMenuService menuService = (IMenuService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench()
            .getService(IMenuService.class);
    if (menuService==null) {
        return;
    }
    menuService.removeContributionFactory(viewMenuAddition);
    viewMenuAddition = null;
    menuService.removeContributionFactory(viewToolbarAddition);
    viewMenuAddition = null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But do I get it right - I disable *all* contributions this way? No way to disable individual contributions, maybe identified by their ids?

Answer (score 0):

Equinox transformations can also be used to supply XLST transformations that remove unwanted UI contributions.