# How to determine which eclipse plugins are contributing to menus and toolbars and stop them

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am creating an RCP app which uses a host of third-party plugins. Some of these plugins contribute menus, menu items, and toolbar buttons that I do not wish to display. How can I determine which plugins are contributing these menus, menu items, and toolbar buttons and how can I disable them from doing so?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To inspect details of menu, toolbar contributions etc.

- Load the Eclipse Plug-in Spy in your RCP application by including the plug-in `org.eclipse.pde.runtime`
- To inspect the current selection, press ALT-SHIFT-F1
- To inspect menus, press ALT-SHIFT-F2 and then select the menu item

Use activities to remove the UI contribution. The "active action definition identifier" value provided by ALT-SHIFT-F2 is the one to use as the pattern in the activityPatternBinding specification. See this question for more info on [removing unwanted UI contributions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415700/disable-plugin-contributions-in-eclipse-rcp-application/6209588).

Note that when using activities to remove unwanted UI contributions, sometimes you will need to specify the UI contributions' plug-in id and sometimes you won't depending on the individual contribution.

NB: The *Plug-in Registry view* can be also used to find the IDs for contributions, although you'll have to do some searching.

Comment: And this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4747839/how-remove-pop-up-menu-contributions-in-eclipse-rcp

Comment: The `locationURI` provided by Plug-in Menu Spy does not work for me when I use it as a `locationURI` when adding one of my own plug-in context menus. Am I missing something, or is this a limitation of Menu Spy?

Comment: It seems the plugin spy only gives the locationURI which is usually just ...?after=additions.  It doesn't give the id of the menu contribution

Answer (score 8):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>
then click some menu.
You can know contributor and menu URI.

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> : inspect current active part and selection.
<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> : inspector contributor of Widget or item.

You needs plugin-spy plugin in runtime.