# How to remove the "Input Methods" menu from my context menu

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, gtk3

I'm developing a RCP application at Centos7, and GTK version is gtk3-3.22.30-3.el7.x86_64.

but there is a sub menu "Input Methods" appeared in all content menu.
[SubMenu.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jsrl0.png)

How can I remove this sub menu.

Comment: You might be able to use the `org.eclipse.ui.activities` extension point to suppress the menu item.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, it's seems like a good way.

Comment: But I don't know about the id of "Input Mthods" menu at all. so that I can't find the ID to disable,sad.

Comment: You can use Eclipse Plug-in and Menu Spy to find out ids - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6209592/2670892)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, my colleague given me an answer.

There is a internal static String variable in org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite named NO_INPUT_METHOD, all we need to do is just set this val not be null by `display.setData("org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.noInputMethod", true);`, then everything is OK!